# Is there a generic way to set the Screen Orientation other than checking for device type in onCreate method of your Activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

This is what I tried , and it works.
In res/values as bool.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">true</bool>
</resources>
```

In res/values-sw600dp and res/values-xlarge:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">false</bool>
</resources>
```

In the onCreate method of my Activities :

```
if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Is there some other way of doing this other than checking in every oncreate method, for EXACTLY THE SAME RESULT

Comment: You can make base activity class for this .

Comment: Hi Krish.. Thx..  base activity and extending it in all other activities will work ... But I feel thats still expensive... and a Base Activity for this onCreate code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you create a base class for an activity like

```
//extending this to all of your activities isnt really that expensive
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }
}

...
OR
```

in your `Application` class register lifecycle callbacks

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
                if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.portrait_only)){
                   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                }
                Log.i(TAG , "ApplicationClass-OnActivityCreated()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
                Log.i(TAG , "ApplicationClass-OnActivityStarted()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
                Log.i(TAG , "ApplicationClass-OnActivityResumed()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
                Log.i(TAG , "ApplicationClass-OnActivityPaused()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
                Log.i(TAG , "ApplicationClass-OnActivityStopped()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
                Log.i(TAG , "ApplicationClass-OnActivitySaveInstanceState()");
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
                Log.i(TAG , "ApplicationClass-OnActivityDestroyed()");
            }
        });

    }
}
```

But i would still prefer the base class implementation.

Hope it helps :)